# Is there any AlertDialog alternative for service?

Tags: android

I am trying to display an `AlertDialog` through my service like this-

```
private void display() {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, "broadcast.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    if (!text.toString().contains("null")) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("BROADCAST").setMessage(text).create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        // don't show
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but It needs the permission in manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Is there anything else I can use to display my text through my service? I do Not want to use this permission, also, I want it through service Only. Not activity.

Comment: Toast or notification is the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has Notifications for this purpose.

If the notification is not sufficient, you can display a notification that can open a "further details" screen using a standard Activity or Dialog themed Activity when pressed.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Remember, the Android support library overrides themes and styles which i'm not using